# How do I make just one of my pages a Blog Page?

Tags: pages, blog, customization

I'm a newbie, so please excuse me.

Notice the "static" nature of my site http://grandeduny.org/. The pages of this site are "wordpress static" by design, but I would like to have one Blog page, how is this done?

I seem to be having a hard time with the concept of making pages unique, for example; how do you have widgets/sidebars on one page but not another? It's not readily apparent from the dashboard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

welcome here... and to WordPress.

To have a blog page, you have to set a page in your dashboard, in *Settings -> Readings* and select a page for stati Home Page a page for Blog Page. [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page#Custom_Blog_Posts_Index_Page_Template) more info.

In general, reading [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Pag) page is a good read for a WP newbie.

How blog index page display the content, depends on your theme. WordPress use to display content different template files for different request.

When you set a blog page, and you visit the related link WordPress check first for a file named `'home.php'`.

You don't have to remember every file is used for every url, you can look at [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) in Codex to easily understand what page is responsible for page display.

You are using *twentytwelve* theme, that's one of the standard wordpress themes, that has no `home.php` file, so according to template hierarchy, the file used to display content is `index.php`.

Being a 'core' theme, this simple task work out of the box: set your blog post page, start to write your articles, and then visit the page, everithing should work fine.

Having different sidebar, based on page, is little more difficult: it cannot be done simply by settings, it needs some code.

So:

- or you write the code by yourself creating a plugin or a child theme
- or you use an already written plugin

If you choose first solution (it's easier that it can appear), start with a search here in wpse, you'll find a lot of exampples and working code snippets. Also in [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar#Multi_sidebars) you can find explainations and code samples.

If you choose second solution, there are different plugins that can do the work, which one to choose is up to you, but try to use well known and frequently updated plugins.

One of the most multiple sidebars plugin, is [WooSidebars](http://www.woothemes.com/woosidebars/) by WooThemes, I've never installed it, but people say works well...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did as you suggested....."To have a blog page, you have to set a page in your dashboard, in Settings -> Readings and select a page for static Home Page a page for Blog Page" I even added a phrase "Let's add some blogs here"............yet I still see no facility (link or button) for initiating a post????

Comment: To add blog posts, go in the dashboard, on the left menu go to *'Posts -> Add New'* and start writing. All the posts you write will be visible in the blog index page. They will be paginated, (a certain number of posts per page) to adjust ne number of posts per page just go in dashboars in *'Settings -> Reading'* and find the option *'Blog pages show at most'* that is 10 by default. I also suggest reading [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/New_To_WordPress_-_Where_to_Start) page.